# Simple cantilever beam deflection - what is the simplest way to add a damper?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, viscosity, structural-beam

I am looking at a simple cantilever beam deflection:

[image]

I understand the [general expression for deflection/force](https://skyciv.com/docs/tutorials/beam-tutorials/deflection-equations/) would be:

$y_s = \frac{Fx_s^3}{3EI}$

$F_p = \frac{3y_sEI}{x_s^3}$

If you were going to add viscous damping to the bending of the beam, would it be as simple as:

$F = \frac{3y_sEI}{x_s^3} - cEIθ_t$

Where the equation for the [angle of deflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deflection_(engineering)) is $θ = \frac{FL^2}{2EI}$?

I have seen some suggestions that simple damping of cantelever beams is done by applying viscosity to the rate of angle change with respect to time. Is that generally correct?

I have had some strange behaviors trying this so I'm not sure what the ideal simple solution is.

Thanks for any help or answers/ideas for either question. It is appreciated.

Comment: Please note [this similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/603943/how-do-i-account-for-damping-on-structural-vibrations) but with no answers.

Comment: The equations presented are for  _static_ deflection of a massless beam. But damping is a dynamic effect, and you need to clarify if the mass of the beam is important or not here. A damper resists motion, but **would not affect the steady-state solution**.

Comment: Hey John. Well I was able to give you an answer that hopefully might help. Thanks for your notes here - I was hoping for a simpler solution than the FDM I posted on your question, but that's simple enough too. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Viscosity is a fluid's resistance to shear, so modeling its effect depends on some fluid parameters. I don't know much about fluid dynamics, so that's all I can say there.

However, it's pretty simple to include some basic damping effects. Simply apply a distributed force similar to $F_d(x, t)= -k\frac{\partial y(x, t)}{\partial t} $, where $k$ is some constant. (This expression holds only in the small deflection limit.)

The intuition here is that the parts of the beam moving faster are resisted upon more. How this distributed force affects $F_p$ depends on the boundary conditions of the cantilever, but I think you can take it from here.

Comment: This would be equivalent to putting a dashpot on every particle of the beam attached to the ground. But this is not how structural damping works. For example, if the entire beam translated up or down would you expect the beam to bend or not. The equation above would impose a distributed load. I am thinking structural damping has to do with resistance to changes in curvature and not changes in deflection. [See this similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/603943/how-do-i-account-for-damping-on-structural-vibrations) that you might have some insight also.

Comment: Oh, I guess I read the question wrong; I thought it was about external damping.